# Android Recyclerview rows created, content provided, but showing blank

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

need another eye on this as I can't figure out what's wrong.

I am able to download the content to fill the recyclerview, I update it and display it, but can't see it on the phone.

With layout inspector I can see I have the two rows created, and the values filled, but again blank

[image]

Let me know which info you want to look at, if any, so we can fix this.

As requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="8dp"
    android:paddingEnd="8dp"
    >


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/tvOtherUserPhotoUrl"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/primary_color"
        app:civ_border_width="2.0dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOtherUserProfilename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:onClick="onChatClick"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOtherUserLastMessage"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvOtherUserProfilename"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:onClick="onChatClick"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:text="Last message"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOtherUserMessageDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:onClick="onChatClick"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="date"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#284033</color>
    <color name="primary_color">#284033</color>
    <color name="secondary_color">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="tertiary_color">#fffb00</color>

    

</resources>
```

Please notice colorPrimary and primary_color are green.
Please notice that there is also an imageview which is not displaying.

Thanks.

Comment: Share your xml file, I have a feeling the text color is set to `#ffffff` so it's invisible !

Comment: Looks like the _RelativeLayoue_ or one of its ancestors has the visibility set to "invisible". This is what you would see and it would include the _ImageView_. Check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment by Cheticamp put me in the right direction. A view above the recyclerview set to GONE did the trick. Thanks.